# android : How to Add ArrayList of object in List View (But not all Attribute)?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have created A Entity class **EventDto**

```
public class EventDTO {
private String eventSourceName;
private String eventTime;
private String eventReason;
private String eventName;


public String getEventSourceName() {
    return eventSourceName;
}

public void setEventSourceName(String eventSourceName) {
    this.eventSourceName = eventSourceName;
}

public String getEventTime() {
    return eventTime;
}

public void setEventTime(String eventTime) {
    this.eventTime = eventTime;
}

public String getEventReason() {
    return eventReason;
}

public void setEventReason(String eventReason) {
    this.eventReason = eventReason;
}

public String getEventName() {
    return eventName;
}

public void setEventName(String eventName) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EventDTO{" +
            ", eventSourceName='" + eventSourceName + '\'' +
            ", eventTime='" + eventTime + '\'' +
            ", eventReason='" + eventReason + '\'' +
            ", eventName='" + eventName + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

and I have created an Array List of type EventDTO

```
public static ArrayList<EventDTO> eventDTOList = new ArrayList<EventDTO>();
```

I have added many events for refernce like bellow multiple tymes.

```
  eventDTOList.add(eventDTO);
```

Now I have List View As following

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/notifications_popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_gradient"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/minimize_notifications"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_header_shape_color"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_notification"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cancel_notifications"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/event_notification"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           />
    </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#fbfdfcfc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/eventList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent
                android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:scrollbarFadeDuration="3000"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now on button click I am adding the array List in List View

```
 final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.eventList);

                ArrayAdapter<EventDTO> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<EventDTO>(GladiusLiveViewActivity.this, R.layout.listview_text_style, eventDTOList);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but Result Have class name and all attribute name included in it 
I want to show only following  two attribute 
2.eventSourceName
3.eventReason

How to do that.

Comment: will fixing the `EventDto.toString()` fix it?

Comment: where I need add that .

Comment: Build the array adapter with 2.eventSourceName 3.eventReason and then set adapter.

Comment: @Haroon can you please provide some sample code in answer section.Sorry but I am quit new to android and java.

Answer (score 0):

you need to override your EventDTO toString()

Something like this

```
@Override
public String toString(){
return this.getEventSourceName() + " - " + this.getEventReason();
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your Pojo. and check if helps

```
public class EventDTO {
private String eventSourceName;
private String eventTime;
private String eventReason;
private String eventName;


public String getEventSourceName() {
    return eventSourceName;
}

public void setEventSourceName(String eventSourceName) {
    this.eventSourceName = eventSourceName;
}

public String getEventTime() {
    return eventTime;
}

public void setEventTime(String eventTime) {
    this.eventTime = eventTime;
}

public String getEventReason() {
    return eventReason;
}

public void setEventReason(String eventReason) {
    this.eventReason = eventReason;
}

public String getEventName() {
    return eventName;
}

public void setEventName(String eventName) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EventDTO{" +
            "eventSourceName='" + eventSourceName + '\'' +
            ", eventReason='" + eventReason + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Comment: I am getting only two field by this but It is is in form of EvntDTO{eventName='SYTEMMEMORY',eventReason='FULL'}

what I need is only SYTEMMEMORY : FULL

Comment: Thanks Haroon for your reply. As You told I have created custom Adaper by taking the help of following post:[link](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)